# Rewriting URL in AJAX application

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, web

I am making a simple online application. 
I have a navigation bar with a few buttons and one "div" into which all the new contents will be loaded dynamically i.e. when I click "About", it will load the page parts into the "div" without reloading the whole page with .load() function. The problem is:
what if I need to give a link to the Documents section of my web site, or the user wants to store this kind of link, the url is not rewritten when browsing my site. when the user stores the default link it will always link him to the default "Home" part.

How can I rewrite the URL and what is the most correct way to do this?

Comment: You could use a hash in the url to identify the section loaded and load the content when gets the page, i.e: http://sample.com#about.
but i think you are missing a bigger problem, which is, your content will not get indexed. ajax is all nice and such, but i think your missusing it.

Comment: look at history.js or jQuery BBQ plugins that change hash in url and in reverse parse the hash so you can load appropriate content. They are designed for ajax friendly bookmarking

Comment: Only recent browsers support the [`history` API](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/). You might want to use [this wrapper](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As option you can use `location.hash`.
E.g. user clicks `<a href="#about">About</a>`
and you're loading the content of your "About" page.
Also the URL in browser's address bar will be changed to something like `http://mysite.com/hello.jsp#about`.

So now user can copy this URL and visit it.

Then in `$(document).ready()` you can check the `location.hash`, find that `'#about'` anchor in it and then load an appropriate content.

---

Another option is to use [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) or any other JavaScript MVC framework that you like which will help you to build rich client-side application and will handle such things for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, appropriate method is to update the hash of the URL. Something like example.com/#About and etc. People can bookmark these. You have to take care to make a AJAX call when you read a hash tag in the URL and load the respective page.

What I would do is make ajax call on [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event instead of click. This event is supported from IE8 to all modern browsers. If you want to support IE7 use the [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) by Ben Alman.